# Real Analysis. Taylor's Formula. Check proof.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

> Let $f: (-1,1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f', f''$ and $f'''$ exist and be continuous in $(-1, 1)$. Assume that $f'(0) = f''(0) = 0$ and $f'''(0) \neq 0$. Show that $f(0)$ isn't a local minimum point.

$\bf{Solution:}$ Using the Taylor's Formula:

$$f(h) - f(0) = \left[\frac{f'''(0)}{3!} + \rho(h)\right]h^{3}$$

where $\displaystyle\rho(h) = \frac{r(h)}{h^{3}}$. Thus, $\lim \rho(h) = 0$.

The signal of $h^{3}$ is the same as $h$. Therefore in a sufficiently small interval around $0$, $f(h) - f(0)$ has no constant signal, independet of the signal of $f'''(0)$. Thus, there is no local minimum in $f(0)$. $\blacksquare$

We can generalize this result to $n$ odd and $a$ arbitrary. The domain of $f$ must be a symmetric interval around $a$?

Is there another way to solve this exercise?

Comment: This is correct and the "right" solution. You needn't have a symmetric interval; all your need is for $0$ (or $a$) to be an interior point of the domain of $f$. You might also consider whether you need the derivatives (in particular, the third derivative) defined on the entire interval in order to get Taylor's formula.

Comment: I think we can simply say this is a **stationary point of inflection** hence not a local minimum, can't we?